# Sum of parts of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, sum, slice

I'm learning to program using the book "Introduction to computation and programming using Python" by John V. Guttag. There is an exercise on it that says the following:

> 'Finger exercise: Let s be a string that contains a sequence of
>   decimal numbers separated by commas, e.g., s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'. Write
>   a program that prints the sum of the numbers in s.'

My try was:

```
#Finger exercise [MIT] PAGE 42     12:50 | 11.10.2015
s = ','+raw_input('Enter a string that contains a sequence of decimal numbers separated by commas, e.g. 1.23,2.4,3.123): ')+','
    total = 0
    for l in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[l] == ',':
            c = l + 1
            while s[c] != ',':
                c = c + 1
                if s[c] == ',':
                    total = total + int(s[int(l),int(c)])
print total
```

but it keeps showing this error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple

I've tried to seek solutions online but only found solutions that work **but not with the content I already now.**
Any help?

Comment: Later when you know the basics, try this `sum(map(float,s.split(',')))`. Works in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a tuple when accessing your string item here:

```
s[int(l),int(c)]
```

Commas generally create tuples.

Instead, you want to use a slice here using a colon:

```
s[int(l):int(c)]
```

Note that both variables are already integers, so you don't actually need to convert them:

```
s[l:c]
```

Also note that you are summing integer values although you accept floats as the input. So instead of adding `int(s[l:c])` you want to add `float(s[l:c])`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no processing of anything before the first comma.

Next, you should comment each part of it at least initially to you are clear what each line is doing.

You shouldn't need to check for a ',' in multiple places, keep a variable.

Comment: Did you read OP’s last sentence? They are bit looking for a “this is how you can do it” solution but a solution to fix *their* code.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found, hope its useful:

```
s = "1.23, 2.4, 3.123"

news = s.split(",")

total = 0 

for string in range(len(news)):    
    total += float(news[string])

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = ''
s = '1.23, 2.4, 3.123'
n = 0.0
for i in s:
    if i != ',':
        total = total + i   
    else: 
        n =  float(total) + n
        total = ''
n = float(total) + n
print(n)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**